# What is the connection string to connect to the master database via SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, odbc

This is possibly a stupid question, but I can't find an answer anywhere else.

I have a SQL database script to restore a number of databases. Via SQL Server 2008, I am able to execute the script by connecting to the 'master' system database.

I'm attempting to automate the execution of this script via a .NET application using OdbcConnection / OdbcCommand classes.

So I need to enter a connection string to be able to execute the script.

Problem is I can't find the connection string for the master database. Is there one?

I tried "DSN=master", but this didn't appear to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [http://connectionstrings.com/](http://connectionstrings.com/) is an excellent resource for connection string examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup a new ODBC Data source in the ODBC Data Source Administrator that has the master database selected.  If you name the DSN "master" then the connection string would indeed be "DSN=master".

Comment: Do you know if setting up a new ODBC data source can be automated via a script? e.g. .NET, DOS command

Comment: there is an odbcadmin tool (or there used to be), that can run via the command line.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/123008

Answer (score 1):

In order to use DSN you have to have an ODBC setup on the machien already and it ust points to that for the connection information.

Bookmark this it will come in hand..

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Every thing you need is in there :)

Comment: Is there any way to automate setting up the ODBC to point to the master database? The test environments I'm running these on will be clean environments each time (otherwise new image snapshots will need to be taken)

Thanks by the way

Comment: This will show you how to have ODBC settings setup with a reg file: http://www.fabalou.com/Access/General/quickodbcinstall.asp in there you can set the default database also. Sorry for long responce time didnt realize you responded :)